# Using String.format() as annotation attribute value

Tags: java, annotations, constants, string-formatting

I have a class that have a number of constants:

```
public class SecurityConstants {
    private static final String HAS_ROLE_TEMPLATE = "hasRole('%s')";

    public static final String ROLE_USER_INTERNAL = "ROLE_USER_INTERNAL";
    public static final String HAS_ROLE_USER_INTERNAL = String.format(HAS_ROLE_TEMPLATE, ROLE_USER_INTERNAL);
}
```

If I then try to use `HAS_ROLE_USER_INTERNAL` as `@PreAuthorize` annotation attribute value like this `@PreAuthorize(SecurityConstants.HAS_ROLE_USER_INTERNAL)` compiler fails with:

> The value for annotation attribute
>   PreAuthorize.value must be a constant
>   expression

However if I change `HAS_ROLE_USER_INTERNAL` to be a simple `String` it works just fine:

```
public static final String HAS_ROLE_USER_INTERNAL = "hasRole('ROLE_USER_INTERNAL')";
```

What's the problem with using `String.format()`? Field is `static` and `final`, what can possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of `String.format()` isn't known at compile time, whereas a `String` literal is.

Since the annotations are metadata on the compiled class, their values must be known by the time the compiler generates the final .class file. Since `String.format()`'s value will only be known once the code is actually *run*, the compiler won't let you use it as part of an annotation.

Comment: Yeah, ok, but it would be so much better if normal `String` literals support formatting in Java. `format("hasRole('%s')", ROLE_NAME)` looks much better than `"hasRole('" + ROLE_NAME + "')"` IMO... or I do too much python programming. :-)

Comment: I know this is real late, @parxier Have you considered enabling the `@Secured` annotation instead (`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)`)? then you can do something like `@Secured({ROLE_NAME})` (role name should have an explicit ROLE_ prefix e.g. `ROLE_NAME = "ROLE_ADMIN";`)

Comment: Sadly Java has no constexpr keyword like C++ :(